# No outputs created using processing-TauDEM and QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, taudem

Has anyone run across this error when trying the New processing-TauDEM plugin in QGIS 3?

> The following layers were not correctly generated:
>
> C:/Users/david.laverty/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_3e96b8dc52a84af0a986623fa57e31f9/4262183f0f124676a16440b55b006d67/PIT_FILLED.tif
>
> You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find
>   more information about the execution of the algorithm.

My Log messages look like this:

> 2018-10-25T11:31:04     INFO    C:/MicrosoftMPI/Bin\mpiexec -n 2
>   C:/PROGRA~1/TauDEM/TauDEM5Exe/pitremove -z
>   C:/Users/david.laverty/Downloads/Ardstraw_02_02_2012/Ardstraw_02_02_2012/DTM_1m/V0900583.asc
>   -fel C:/Users/david.laverty/AppData/Local/Temp/processing_3e96b8dc52a84af0a986623fa57e31f9/4262183f0f124676a16440b55b006d67/PIT_FILLED.tif

I have tried this as a TEMP layer save and as a save layer option but still I get the same result. There is nothing in the Log Messages regarding TauDEM and in the TEMP folder where the output is supposed to be saved there is nothing.

My TauDEM is working correctly as I am able to run the commands from my QGIS 2.18 install and also from the command line.

Has anyone else had this happen to them using the new TauDEM provider plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see answer here I have posted on how to deal with this error

[Adding TauDEM provider to QGIS 3?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/272797/adding-taudem-provider-to-qgis-3/313785#313785)